# How does one estimate parameters in a GARCH-M(1,1) model?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, garch

Say you have a GARCH-M(1,1) model as follows:

$y_t = \beta y_{t-1} + \delta h_t + \epsilon_t, \quad \epsilon_t \sim N(0, h_t) $

$h_t = a_0 + a_1 \epsilon^2_{t-1} + b_1 h_{t-1}.$

How exactly does one estimate the parameter vector: $\Theta = (\delta, \beta, a_0, a_1, b_1)^\top$? [This paper](https://ir.lib.uwo.ca/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3164&context=etd), shows the likelihood function for estimating the parameters in the model using the MLE method. For those who have applied this or a similar methodology, are there any nuances to take note of during the estimation process?

Comment: You can use M.L.E. to estimate parameter vector.

Comment: Thanks @Neeraj but I need more detail. What is the form of the conditional log-likelihood?

Comment: Have you tried looking this up in the research paper that proposed the model the first time? Or in some textbook?

Comment: @RichardHardy the univariate GARCH-M was not explicitly implemented in the form above but in the multivariate case by Engle, Lilien and Robins (1987). The ARCH-M was the first to be implemented though. I have found a paper, however, that writes down the log-likelihood, just wanted some advice on the nuances. I hope that by the end of the day I would have answered the question.

Comment: You could mention the sources you found helpful explicitly by editing your post. Perhaps they will be helpful for other users in the future.